# How to iterate through each array item and insert to database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Here I have an array with 4 items. My PHP script is iterating through each array item and should insert it into the database. Right now I am not able to insert all values into the database, it is only adding the record for the last array item. How can I do that?

Here's what I have done:

```
$project_id = $_GET["pid"];
$today = date('Y-m-d');
$session_array = array("session-1","session-2","session-3","session-4");

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

foreach ($session_array as $sesname) {
    $session_name = $sesname;
    $sql = "INSERT INTO project_sessions (session_date,session_name,project_id) VALUES ('$today','$session_name',$project_id)";
}

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
        header("Location: show-project.php?id=$project_id");
} else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}
mysqli_close($conn);
```

Comment: Move `mysqli_query($conn, $sql)` in `foreach`, isn't it simple?

Comment: @u_mulder thank you!!! it worked

Answer (score 0):

put mysql mysqli_query($conn, $sql) inside loop.

```
$project_id = $_GET["pid"];
$today = date('Y-m-d');
$session_array = array("session-1","session-2","session-3","session-4");

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
$error = 0;
foreach ($session_array as $sesname) {
    $session_name = $sesname;
    $sql = "INSERT INTO project_sessions (session_date,session_name,project_id) VALUES ('$today','$session_name',$project_id)";
    if (!mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
        $error = 1;
        $error_sql = $sql;
    }
}

if (!$error) {
    header("Location: show-project.php?id=$project_id");
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $error_sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}
mysqli_close($conn);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, more efficient way...

```
$project_id = $_GET["pid"];
$today = date('Y-m-d');
$session_array = array("session-1","session-2","session-3","session-4");

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO project_sessions (session_date,session_name,project_id) VALUES";

$startLoop = false;
foreach ($session_array as $sesname) {
    $session_name = $sesname;
    $sql .= ($startLoop)?',':'';
    $sql .= "('$today','$session_name',$project_id)";
    $startLoop = true;
}

if($startLoop){
    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
            header("Location: show-project.php?id=$project_id");
    } else {
            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
    }
}
mysqli_close($conn);
```